# Making CSS3 Gradient Background Spin

Tags: jquery, animation, css, webkit, gradient

I've set a CSS3 background gradient on an item, and I'd like to have it spin slowly. I'm just starting with CSS3 & HTML5 (Mind you, I've used CSS & HTML for 15 years, there's a lot of new stuff though). Is it possible to spin just the background, not the actual element?

**(Removed link to page, as it no longer exists)** It is a background gradient even though it's on the text's foreground, gotta love background-clip); I don't want the text to rotate but I do want the background to. Also, this only works in webkit browsers.

I'm willing to use whatever scripting gets it done - HTML5 canvas, CSS3 transforms, Javascript/jQuery, etc (although keeping it pure CSS3 would be great). I am trying to avoid using any images, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by animating the CSS property with JavaScript.  Here is an example that uses a bit of jQuery to ease changing the CSS:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HYDAj/2/

Basically, I use `setInterval` to change the gradient angle every 100ms.  I couldn't get your specific gradient to work, and this example only works in WebKit browsers, but that will get you started.

I should also note that WebKit is alone in supporting `background-clip: text', so that is another reason this won't work in Firefox or IE.

In case you didn't care to use any jQuery, here is the pure JavaScript way:

http://jsfiddle.net/HYDAj/3/

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! Meets my needs perfectly. As for the WebKit limitations, it's almost a proof of concept at this point - I'm sure I'll end up doing it another way. Just wanted to see if I could make my design idea in pure code.